# Is it possible to create an image library in iTextsharp?

Tags: c#, image, pdf, itext

I would like to know if it's possible to add the images to a PDF using iTextsharp in such a way that you don't necessarily add the images directly onto the page, but instead first add them into a library and then you reference the library as required in your PDF.

The advantage of this approach is that if you re-use the same image it will no longer add an exact duplicate of the image into the PDF but just re-use the current copy of the image.

I have done some tests so far:

```
Actual image size: 102kB
1 copy of the image in the PDF + other text: 259kB
2 copies of the image in the PDF + other text: 481kB
3 copies...: 704kB
4 copies...: 926kB
```

From this it's clear that the PDF isn't smart enough to know that I'm re-using the same image and simply referencing it. It would be truly great if it could be...

Comment: Do you mean a library within the document itself, so the reuse is only within the document?

Comment: I think he wanna mean to use the Dictionary and use a reference to the object of image.

Comment: If you supplied your code, the error would have been obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Images are stored in a PDF as Image XObjects. XObject is short for eXternal Object. It means that the bits and bytes of the image aren't stored in the content stream of a page.

When used correctly, iText will add the bits and the bytes of an image in such an XObject and reuse it whenever needed. If you add the same image more than once and the file size grows, you aren't using iText correctly.

See [Chapter 3 of the tutorial "iText 7: Building Blocks"](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-3-using-ileafelement-implementations) and compare the [MaryReillyV2](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/examples/chapter-3#1925-c03e09_maryreillyv2.java) example with the [MaryReillyV3](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/examples/chapter-3#1926-c03e10_maryreillyv3.java) example.

This is correct:

```
Image img = new Image(ImageDataFactory.create(MARY));
document.add(img);
document.add(img);
```

It creates a document with file size 16 KB.

This is wrong:

```
Image img1 = new Image(ImageDataFactory.create(MARY));
document.add(img1);
Image img2 = new Image(ImageDataFactory.create(MARY));
document.add(img2);
```

It creates a document with file size 31 KB.

Both PDF look identical to the naked eye:

[image]

The only difference is that the 16 KB PDF was created by someone who read the manual, whereas the 31 KB PDF was created by someone who didn't.

The file `mary_reilly_V1.pdf` is a PDF file to which we've added the image only once. As you notice, the difference in file size with the PDF to which we've correctly added the image twice is almost identical.

**Extra remark**

The answer is about iText 7, but the same principle is true for iText 5.